# Basic arithmetic on variables

Tags: c++

So I have a doubt as to what the following piece of code does to the variable.

```
int t=0;


t +50;


cout<<t;
```

Does the 2nd line work the same as as t+=50? I came across this is in a question and quite didn't know what it did.

Comment: While syntactically correct (compiles without error), odds are good that the compiler will emit a warning over `t +50;` because it does absolutely nothing. Warnings are very helpful. They are the first line of defense against logic errors so turn them on and turn them up ***LOUD*** so you can't ignore them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the 2nd line work the same as as t+=50?

No. the statement `t + 50;` is not an assignment statement, it is an expression whose result is ignored because it is not assigned to any variable.

`t+=50;` is simply equivalent to `t = t + 50;`

so the output here will still be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

t + 50 will add 50 to the variable t and the result is gone forever unless you assigned it to another value.

You need to study programming with C++ from the beginning mate!

I recommend Big C++ refrence